# bootstrap accordion is not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

my bootstrap 2.3 accordion is not working properly
it works only for one time clicking on tabs again it doesn't work
here is my code:
and this is the link where i want to place my accordion
http://etekstudio.org/demo/crateen/test-featured

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no I'm including 2.3 bootstrap.js ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of your page include this:
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Replace the code with this:

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      Product description
    </a>
    </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
    TEST STUFF
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
      Reviews
    </a>
    </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
   Your Review Code Here
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

`

Comment: its working fine here
http://crateen.com/women5/big-flower-ring1
js files are included in head section

Comment: With that code? (An up vote and / or a check would be nice :) )

Comment: Include those at the bottom of your page before the </body> tag

Comment: yes with same lines that you've sent in head section

Comment: I've other JS files, should i need to add all other js files before </body> ?